# Processes at $10^{-13}$ cm and smaller

Tags: quantum-mechanics, renormalization, history

I am reading the paper by David Bohm, "A Suggested Interpretation of the Quantum Theory in Terms of "Hidden" Variables. I". My question is not about Bohmian mechanics. However, he mentions something interesting:

> the quantum theory with its usual probability interpretation is in
> excellent agreement with an extremely wide range of experiments, at
> least in the domain of distances' larger than 10$^{-13}$cm ...

and then goes on to mention

> At distances of the order 10^{-13} cm or smaller and for times on the order of this distance divided by the velocity of light or smaller, present theories became so inadequate that it is generally believed that they are probably not applicable, except perhaps in a very crude sense. Thus, it is generally expected that in connection with phenomena associated with this so-called "fundamental length," a totally new theory will probably be needed.

I would like to understand this better. Is he referring to the conceptual difficulties surrounding what we now call renormalization (group)? What were the state-of-the-art arguments for and against the notion that quantum mechanics itself was sick at scales shorter than $10^{-13}$ cm? Clearly quantum mechanics turned out to be sufficient to describe these processes: what is the *modern* response to the objection alluded to by David Bohm in the paper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A wavelength of $10^{-15}$m corresponds to an energy of about $1$ GeV i.e. the mass of a proton and/or neutron so I think Bohm is referring to the fact that at the time of writing (1951) the strong force was not understood.

In 1951 quantum electrodynamics was well established, and I think renormalisation was understood by then, but quantum chromodynamics would not be formulated for another decade. The world of the hadrons seemed a bewildering zoo of particles with little obvious structure. That meant there was no theory to describe what happened at energies above a GeV or so.

Exactly what Bohm meant by saying that an entirely new theory may be required only he knew and the secret died with him. However it is possible that he meant [S matrix theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix_theory). In the 1960s various apparently intractable problems with applying quantum field theory to hadrons resulted in S matrix theory becoming a popular competitor to quantum field theory. With the later discovery of quarks, and in particular asymptotic freedom, QFT regained a lead that it has held ever since. However there was a period when many physicists believed that QFT would fail and S matrix theory would take over.

Comment: Thank you, but this answer is not complete enough for me to accept it yet.

Comment: @Diffycue What more would be required to satisfy you?

Comment: Bohm is referencing the unsolved state of processes at short length scales in 1951 as a motivation for his/de Broglie's reinterpretation of quantum mechanics. Of course, now we know that the reinterpretation is not necessary. But what was it about the short-distance processes and the zoo of particles that suggested otherwise? E.g. were there unitarity violations? What about these processes was endangering QM itself?

Comment: @Diffycue Is that better? There is an excellent talk by Steven Weinberg that describes the history of QFT and its tussle with S matrix theory. If you're interested I can attempt to find a link.

Comment: [What is Quantum Field Theory, and What Did We Think It Is?](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9702027)

Comment: Thanks, that is a good read. However the S matrix issue seems a red herring. If that program had been successful then the need for quantum *fields* rather than quantum *mechanics* would have been obviated, so I don't think Bohm had that in mind. We probably must settle with speculation. After reading some interviews with Bohm, he seems to have been familiar with renormalization theory although not expert in it.

Comment: My own speculation is that the requirements of publication in a physics journal were the primary motivation for mentioning the unsettled case of the short-distance processes, and that privately Bohm did not have a strong argument that quantum theory could not describe those processes but if he relied on purely philosophical motivation then the paper would be less likely to be considered.

Comment: The late 40's/early 50's was the era of the discovery of "strange particles". Some of the fragments emerging from high-energy interactions with nuclei were not the protons, neutrons, and pions expected to be present. Then, there was renormalization, considered a blemish on the theory. So, a common idea was that somehow the rules changed at short distances.